# Bootstrap Column, make hidden rather than go under

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 divs

```
 <div class="col-lg-10 hidden-md">ABC</div>
 <div class="col-lg-2  hidden-md">123</div>
```

"ABC" has content that won't resize (intentional)

When there isn't enough room to fit "123", Bootstrap will move it under "ABC". I want "123" to **disappear** in this case, not ever go "**under**".

Is there a way?

Note I have hidden it for md and below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** This code is Bootstrap 3 specific - see [Alec's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592105/bootstrap-column-make-hidden-rather-than-go-under/28593131?noredirect=1#comment115120519_28593131) for Bootstrap 4 information.

The `hidden-md` class doesn't actually hide the element for viewports *at or below* the "medium" viewport width, it hides the element when the viewport falls into the medium width *only*.

You should be able to use the Bootstrap `.visible` classes to [hide certain elements with this class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) when the viewport is smaller than a specified size.  In this case, the second `<div>` will only show when the viewport is "large", and disappear when the viewport is smaller than "large" (i.e. medium, small, etc.).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">ABC</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 visible-lg">123</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEzwYg) - try stretching and shrinking the browser's width to see what's going on.

Comment: how do you do the same in ReactStrap

Comment: @tatsu This answer pertains to Bootstrap 3.  I think you'd *probably* do it in ReactStrap like you'd do it [in Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/).

Comment: unfortunately no I think this may not be available under ReactStrap. thanks thought. TIL

Comment: This has changed for Bootstrap 4. Visible only of 
 lg: `.d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: @Alec I've updated my answer to reflect that this is outdated - thanks!